# C# Html parsing

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse HTML in my C# project without success, I am using a HtmlAgilityPack lib to do so, I can get some of the HTML body text but not all of it for some reason.
I need to grab the div with ID of latestPriceSection, and filter to the USD value from https://www.monero.how/widget

My function (doesn't work)

```
public void getXMRRate()
{
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = web.Load("https://www.monero.how/widget");
    HtmlNode[] nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a").Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains("latestPriceSection")).ToArray();
    foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the document string contains the html you think it does?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. As long as I don't : Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains("latestPriceSection")).ToArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't work because the widget is updated via script. The div contains nothing when you load the page. You can't use HAP to scrape the information of this. Find a web service that can give you the information you need.

Alternatively you can use Selenium to get the HTML after the page has loaded the script. Or you the WebBrowser class, but that requires you to have a form application where the form contains the WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve JSON-data from https://www.monero.how/widgetLive.json, because widget use this resource in Ajax request.